# Laravel Cashier - publish migration results in "cannot declare class CreateCustomersColumns"

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I have a fresh Laravel installation and I've added Cashier to my project.

Since the `Users` model on my app won't have a stripe connection, but rather an `Accounts` model, I need to alter their migration to add columns to `Accounts` instead of `Users`

The documentation says to run:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cashier-migrations"`

which adds the two migration files to `database/migrations`

From there I can change `users` to `accounts` in the migration file.

When I try to run `php artisan migrate`, I get:

`Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Cannot declare class CreateCustomerColumns, because the name is already in use`

This problem only goes away when I delete the migration files, but then the new columns are added to `users`.

Comment: check your migration files you must creating CreateCustomerColumns class. change the name of that class. It is already being used somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that you can disable their migration files by putting `Cashier::ignoreMigrations();` in `AppServiceProvider`

I didn't realize that's what I wanted to do. I thought the publish command only published the two files I needed to edit, however, those are the only migration files that come with Cashier.

Be sure to add `Cashier::ignoreMigrations();` in the `register` method.

And add `use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;`

Answer (score 0):

The file (and thus the class) must exist twice, probably in your database/migrations directory, most likely with 2 different datetime prefixes on the filenames.